# Very bad performance when accepting an SSL socket

Tags: c#, .net, performance, ssl

I have a client and server application written in C# on .NET 4.5 that are using an SslStream to communicate.

However, on the first launch of either the client or server, setting up the SslStream is extremely slow, usually taking on the order of 8-10 seconds.

I've loaded the application up in dotTrace and found that the majority of the time is being spent in our AcceptConnection method (which is, itself, called as part of our callback from Socket.BeginAccept()), as shown in the dotTrace call trace below:

[image: dotTrace output]

The source code from our SocketManager class that generated the above trace is (with logging statements removed for brevity):

```cs
public void AcceptConnection( ClientCommunicationManager ccm )
{
    _ns = new NetworkStream( Sock, true );
    _sslStream = new SslStream( _ns, true );
    X509Store certs = new X509Store( StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine );
    certs.Open( OpenFlags.ReadOnly );
    X509Certificate2 machineCert = certs.Certificates.Find( X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, Environment.MachineName, true )[ 0 ];
    certs.Close( );

    _sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer( machineCert, true, SslProtocols.Tls12, true );

    _sslStream.BeginRead( ReceiveBuffer, 0, ReceiveBuffer.Length, ReceiveData, ccm );
}
```

The following code from our ClientCommunicationManager class is what resulted in the AcceptConnection function being called:

```
private void AcceptClientConnection( IAsyncResult ar )
{
    ClientCommunicationManager ccm = ar.AsyncState as ClientCommunicationManager;
    Socket acceptedSocket = _listenerSocket.EndAccept( ar );
    SocketManager manager = new SocketManager( ccm, acceptedSocket );
    _listenerSocket.BeginAccept( AcceptClientConnection, this );

    manager.AcceptConnection( this );
}
```

dotTrace claims that 97.95% of the time in that function was spent in the call to "ProcessAuthentication," which isn't something I explicitly called, so I don't know what spawned that call.

The server has a valid CA-signed certificate and it is installed in the local machine personal store.

I've scoured google for the past couple of days and am running into a brick wall.
Any suggestions on how I can determine the cause of this delay?

Comment: Is it any faster when the `clientCertificateRequired` (2nd) parameter to `AuthenticateAsServer` is `false`? When this is `true`, the server sends the list of acceptable client certificate issuers (apparently taken from the machine's  which could be potentially sizeable. On my machine it sends about 200 separate entries (resulting in about 20KB of data being sent to the client), if yours is many more it may result in the poor performance you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I made that change, though, and it still took a long time (13 seconds).

Comment: Edits made to the question (including new dotTrace output).  Seems I had mis-traced the problem.  The AuthenticateAsServer method itself is not necessarily the problem - it's this ProcessAuthentication method, which I'm not explicitly calling.

Comment: It may be making a web request for the CRL to verify that the client certificate has not been revoked by the issuer. You could try disabling revocation checking (think that's the last parameter to `AuthenticateAsServer`).

Comment: I made that change myself early on, as well, thinking maybe the CRL check could be slow.  It unfortunately does not seem to help.  I may have misdirected you with my original question.  I've made some fairly significant edits to the question now, to clarify.  I'm not so sure the AuthenticateAsServer method has anything to do with it, any more, by the looks of the new dotTrace output above.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me, does your computer have an internet connection? If not, because these are signed dll's windows will be trying to download a CRL from its server to ensure that these files have not been tampered with. Try disabling "Check for publisher revocation" in Internet Explorer.
Otherwise try putting into your application a config file alongside your .exe of the same name example  applicationName.exe.config

This file should contain

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, this system has internet connectivity.  Unfortunately, this did not help the problem.